# What is the difference between returning object list as List<Object> and into Response in jersey

Tags: jersey

What are the pros and cons of using

```
@GET
    @Path("....
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response objects (...
    return Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK).entity(objects).build();
```

and

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Test> getTestsBrowser() {
    List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();
    tests.addAll(TestDao.instance.getModel().values());
    return tests; 
  }
```

Does one of the methods is better in terms of the flexibility for the json model (meaning returning more complex model for example two types of objects that have reference to each other). Also what if the list is empty or null?